# Using prepared PDO statement with PHP - binary numbers

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm relatively inexperienced with php, pdo and sql. that being said, I have been working on a small project and while most things are working as intended i'm having some issues. 
take the following information from the mysql (mariadb) database

```
| Field  | Type   | Null | Key | Default  | Extra  |
| age    | bit(6) | YES  |     | NULL     |        |
```

In the PHP I have a simple form where you enter your age, eg. mine is 33.

```
$age=decbin($_POST['age']);
```

this correctly shows 100001 when i echo $age.
using my (possibly horrible) pdo statements

```
    $stmt = $DBH->prepare("INSERT INTO Recruit(recruit_id, name, age) VALUES(:recruit_id,:name,:age)");
    $stmt->execute(array(':recruit_id' => $recruit_id, ':name' => $name, ':age' => $age));
```

recruit_id and name both show up without issue, but age always populates as 111111 regardless of what i enter as the age.

I've tried doing cast(:age as binary(6)) with the same results. I'm simply at a loss of how to accomplish this task.

*****corrected typo in the database paste*****

i have changed age to an integer, however, i still yes a couple on/off options that are stored as binary(1) and the same issue presents. php can show the value as a 1 or 0 correctly, but when sent to the db, it is always a 1.  (age presented a good example as all 6 bits were 1)

Comment: I've got a bad feeling about the `Type` column. What's your intent on using the `BIT` type?

Comment: ^ asking myself the same thing.

Comment: Moi ausi mon ami. Why would you want to store an age (an obvious integer) as binary?

Comment: Also you are trying to assign 6 bits to a `bit(4)` columns ??? 6 =/= 4 if fact if I remember my maths class 6 > 4

Comment: sorry i pasted the wrong portion of sql.. the field is age of type bit(6) my apologies!! I'll edit the OP   as a side note, the upper age limit allowed happens to be 63 binary just made it extremely easy to limit this.. isn't 6 bits more efficient than a 2 digit integer?

Comment: Agree with other comments that you seem to be gaining nothing but complexity by using a binary field type here.  If you were using integer field, you would have never even encountered this problem and be working on something else in your application. Not too mention that you will now have to make binary->interer conversion in your application every time you want to prepare to display this value to a human.

Comment: ok pretend it's a on or off state requiring an input of 1 or 0. the same situation occurs, it is always written to the db as a 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: After further research, it sounds like my previous answer wont work for the method you are using as parameters passed to the `execute` function are all treated as `PDO::PARAM_STR`. You'll want to bind them all separately and use `PDO::PARAM_INT` for the age variable. Like so:

```
$stmt = $DBH->prepare("INSERT INTO Recruit(recruit_id, name, age) VALUES(:recruit_id,:name,:age)");
$stmt->bindParam(':recruit_id', $recruit_id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':age', $age, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
```

---

(PREVIOUS ANSWER)

From [MySQL Reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/bit-type.html):

> To specify bit values, b'value' notation can be used. value is a binary value written using zeros and ones. For example, b'111' and b'10000000' represent 7 and 128, respectively.

So I'd try this instead: `$age = "b'".decbin($_POST['age'])."'";`

Comment: i tried this with the same results. i updated the OP with some notes. age is now simply an integer, but i have some on/off, they still are sent as 1's regardless of how it's stored. php can display it properly.

Comment: @driz I probably should have looked up `decbin` earlier. That function returns a string. So just pass the `$age` value directly to the database, without putting it through `decbin`.